# How to escape dot in my data in JsRender templates

Tags: jsrender

Unfortunately my json data looks something like this :

```
{
    "SAK": {
        "SA.TITTEL" : "The title",
        "SA.ANSVFIRMANAVN" : "The name",
        "SA.ANSVFIRMAID" : "An id"
    }
}
```

And makes it pretty hard to make a template, for when I tell the JsRender {{:SAK.SA.TITTEL}} it fails (understandable).

There should be a way to escape that DOT to make JsRender to understand what I mean. Something like

```
{{:SAK."SA.TITTEL"}}
```

or

```
{{:SAK.SA\.TITTEL}}
```

But neither of those work and I have been unable to find any way around that. 
Hope someone knows how to do that.

Best regards,
Armaz Mellati

Comment: Not having any knowledge of jsrender, but just of js, couldn't you do `myobj.SAK["SA\.TITTEL"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write

```
{{:SAK["SA.TITTEL"]}}
```

If the top-level property has a dot, then use `#data["..."]` - so if you had

```
{
  "SA.K": {
      "SA.TITTEL" : "The title",
```

then you could write:

```
{{:#data[SA.K]["SA.TITTEL"]}}
```